# Why VS2012 doesn't create new language file for me?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, localization, windows-phone

**What I want:**
add new languages support for my windows phone app

**What I refer:**
MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx
The Document say:

> Visual Studio has created a new resource file for each supported
>   language that is a copy of the neutral resource file
>   (AppResources.resx) and renamed it to include the locale code that
>   reflects the new resource file’s Culture.

**What happened?**
After I add new languages in the project properties windows,and I save and build the solution.
Nothing happened.....

**Why and how to solve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly the automatic generation of the AppResources.resx files only seems to work for Windows Phone 8 apps. For Windows Phone 7 apps you have to do it all manually. This is how to localize your app in Windows Phone 7:

**Step 1:**
Choose languages in "Supported Cultures" in project properties (same as for WP8)

**Step 2:**
Right click on project in solution explorer -> Add -> New Item...

**Step 3:**
Select the type `Resources File` and name it `AppResources.resx`

**Step 4:**
Open the `AppResources.resx` file and change the `Access Modifier` to `Public`:

[image]

**Step 5:**
Repeat step 2, 3, and 4 for every other language you want to use, naming the file `AppResources.<culture>.resx`, for example `AppResources.sv.resx` for Swedish.

**Step 6:**
Create a class named "LocalizedStrings.cs" with the following code:

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
    private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();

    public AppResources AppResources
    {
        get { return _localizedResources; }
    }
}
```

**Step 7:**
Open App.xaml, and add the following to `<Appllication.Resources>`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
</Application.Resources>
```

**Step 8:**
You can now use the translations in the following way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding AppResources.Title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

Where `Title` is the `Name` column in the AppResources.resx files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I even check if the MSDN solution supports WP7 and it said "WP OS 7.1 and 8" -_-

Comment: Ye, I saw that too, but must be wrong, I also tried on two machines where it worked for WP8 but not WP7.